# Replacing row values in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I would like to replace row values in pandas.

In example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

a = np.array(([100, 100, 101, 101, 102, 102],
                 np.arange(6)))
pd.DataFrame(a.T)
```

Result:

```
array([[100,   0],
       [100,   1],
       [101,   2],
       [101,   3],
       [102,   4],
       [102,   5]])
```

Here, I would like to replace the rows with the values `[101, 3]` with `[200, 10]` and the result should therefore be:

```
array([[100,   0],
       [100,   1],
       [101,   2],
       [200,  10],
       [102,   4],
       [102,   5]])
```

**Update**

In a more general case I would like to replace multiple rows.

Therefore the old and new row values are represented by nx2 sized matrices (n is number of row values to replace). In example:

```
old_vals = np.array(([[101, 3]],
                     [[100, 0]],
                     [[102, 5]]))

new_vals = np.array(([[200, 10]],
                     [[300, 20]],
                     [[400, 30]]))
```

And the result is:

```
array([[300,  20],
       [100,   1],
       [101,   2],
       [200,  10],
       [102,   4],
       [400,  30]])
```

Comment: You'll have to define for multiple row-case as it depends

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the single row case:

```
In [35]:

df.loc[(df[0]==101) & (df[1]==3)] = [[200,10]]
df
Out[35]:
     0   1
0  100   0
1  100   1
2  101   2
3  200  10
4  102   4
5  102   5
```

For the multiple row-case the following would work:

```
In [60]:

a = np.array(([100, 100, 101, 101, 102, 102],
                 [0,1,3,3,3,4]))
df = pd.DataFrame(a.T)
df
Out[60]:
     0  1
0  100  0
1  100  1
2  101  3
3  101  3
4  102  3
5  102  4
In [61]:

df.loc[(df[0]==101) & (df[1]==3)] = 200,10
df
Out[61]:
     0   1
0  100   0
1  100   1
2  200  10
3  200  10
4  102   3
5  102   4
```

For multi-row update like you propose the following would work where the replacement site is a single row, first construct a dict of the old vals to search for and use the new values as the replacement value:

```
In [78]:

old_keys = [(x[0],x[1]) for x in old_vals]
new_valss = [(x[0],x[1]) for x in new_vals]
replace_vals = dict(zip(old_keys, new_vals))
replace_vals
Out[78]:
{(100, 0): array([300,  20]),
 (101, 3): array([200,  10]),
 (102, 5): array([400,  30])}
```

We can then iterate over the dict and then set the rows using the same method as my first answer:

```
In [93]:

for k,v in replace_vals.items():
    df.loc[(df[0] == k[0]) & (df[1] == k[1])] = [[v[0],v[1]]]
df
     0  1
0  100  0
     0  1
5  102  5
     0  1
3  101  3
Out[93]:
     0   1
0  300  20
1  100   1
2  101   2
3  200  10
4  102   4
5  400  30
```

Comment: Thank you for the anwser. For the general (multiple-row) case, I meant that also the new values change: therefore the old and new values are representer by a nx2 sized arrays.

Comment: So did my answer fulfil that criteria or not, if not you'll have to post desired output

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way should be this one:

```
df.loc[[3],0:1] = 200,10
```

In this case, 3 is the third row of the data frame while 0 and 1 are the columns.

This code instead, allows you to iterate over each row, check its content and replace it with what you want.

```
target = [101,3]
mod = [200,10]

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row[0] == target[0] and row[1] == target[1]:
        row[0] = mod[0]
        row[1] = mod[1]

print(df)
```

Comment: I think your first example should be: `df.iloc[3,0:1] = 200,10` - at least this is what worked in newwer versions of pandas for me.

Answer (score 3):

Replace 'A' with 1 and 'B' with 2.

```
df = df.replace(['A', 'B'],[1, 2])
```

This is done over the *entire DataFrame* no matter the column.

However, we can target a single column in this way

```
df[column] = df[column].replace(['A', 'B'],[1, 2])
```

More in-depth examples are available [HERE](https://www.statology.org/pandas-replace-values/).

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is:

```
import io

a = np.array(([100, 100, 101, 101, 102, 102],
                 np.arange(6)))
df = pd.DataFrame(a.T)

string = df.to_string(header=False, index=False, index_names=False)

dictionary = {'100  0': '300  20',
              '101  3': '200  10',
              '102  5': '400  30'}

def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.items():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text

string = replace_all(string, dictionary)
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(string), delim_whitespace=True)
```

I found this solution better, since when dealing with large amount of data to replace, the time is shorter than by EdChum's solution.